# Can I receive data from .rdlc Report Parameters?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parameters, report, rdlc, report-designer

I have a VS 2010 Report, and I would like to pass values that are calculated inside of one .rdlc report to another.  Can I somehow use the Parameters to send data back out of the report, or have some "return" value from the .RDLC?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have return values with report services.

Instead, assuming that the two report have different dataset, the only solution I come out so far is to include two dataset in your second report and recalculate your field.
Doing that, you can use your normal expression to calculate the values that you need from the first report specifying the first dataset.

Here really simple example:

**Report 1**

The report is using only the `DataSet1`

`=Fields!AField.Value`

---

**Report 2**

The report is using two dataset: `DataSet1` and `DataSet2`

`=(Fileds!AField.Value, "DataSet1") + (Fields!AnotherField.Value, "DataSet2")`

Ofc the expressions could be more complex, but the most important thing is to specify the DataSet where the report have to take the filed.